# Why does this not load the ids of the contents in the BoxLayout? (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Why does this code get a KeyError, from line #21?

I've tried different versions of similar code, but this is the only file that gets the KeyError.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/464ae3ae3ddd7d33a9eb64d856acacd0

Why is it missing the id's of each element in the Kivy file?

How come the function beneath the **init**() function works, with that exact same line of code--but the init() function doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `record_new_model` gets called.

Your constructor fails so the rest doesn't matter.

You aren't setting the ids properly.

You need to do something like this

```
<ModelAddLayout>:

   model_add_name: model_add_name

   orientation: 'vertical'
   padding: 20, 20

   Label:
      id: title_label
      text: 'Model Add Screen'
      font_size: '30dp'
      # text_size: '15dp'

   TextInput:
      id: model_add_name
      text: 'Add your model name here'
      multiline: False
```

When you are adding an id to a child it doesn't get added to the parent. You also need to add the id to the parent: `model_add_name: model_add_name`.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. I've successfully called child id's in the past without initializing an id with the parent. The reason it works with other code, and not this one has something to do with the root. The root determines what elements get loaded into the code first. For this code is ScreenManagement. The root for others is ModelAddLayout. So, for the code I linked, it loads the elements of the kv file later than I expect, so there are no keys in the ids attribute to call.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, btw. I'm not just brushing it off. What I did get to work was to put everything except super() into a new function, late_init(self, keys, **largs). After that, I put Clock.schedule_once(self.late_init, 0) after __init__()'s super. This gave the app time to populate the ids, enabling my dropdown list to become a reality.

Comment: Yeah, that happens sometimes. If you want the exact moment a widget is added you can implement on_model_add_name in your controller class. Kivy calls methods named on_widget_id for you whenever the value for widget_id changes. I think you need to define widget_id as ObjectProperty for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The root determines what elements get loaded into the code first.

For this code is ScreenManagement. The root for others is ModelAddLayout.

So, for the code I linked, it loads the elements of the kv file later than I expect, so there are no keys in the ids attribute to call.

What I did get to work, then,  was to put everything except super() into a new function, late_init(self, keys, **largs).

After that, I put Clock.schedule_once(self.late_init, 0) after **init**()'s super.

This gave the app time to populate the ids, enabling my dropdown list to become a reality.

(From the comment to Radu Dita's answer.)